# Unable to establish websocket connection using Mosquitto Broker javascript client

Tags: websocket, mqtt

I am running a MQTT server (mosquitto) on my windows machine. The service is running on port number 1883.

Downloaded the mosquitto.js file from mosquitto.org and making the call as below 
When I debug I see the result "connection.readyState == 0". Kindly help me out if I am missing out something. I am using chrome and safari latest versions to test it.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="./js/mosquitto-1.1.js"></script> 

<title>publisher</title>

</head>

<body>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Publisher</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><textarea rows="5" cols="25" id="txtMsg"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input type="button" value="post"
                            onclick="javaScript:postMessage();" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function postMessage()
{

    var postVal = document.getElementById('txtMsg').value;
    var t = new Mosquitto();
    t.connect('ws://localhost',100000);
    t.publish('inbox/msgrec',postVal,0,0);

}
```

Is it necessary that I have to install jetty server or use node.js to connect using mosquitto javascript client, or is it necessary that I do any changes to the configuration file in my mosquitto installation.

Answer (score 7):

Mosquitto doesn't directly support WebSockets. You need something else that does and will translate the WebSocket connection carrying MQTT packets (as generated by e.g. mosquitto.js) into raw MQTT.

The server at test.mosquitto.org has lighttpd running as the webserver, with mod_websockets to provide WebSockets support. It is possible to connect to ws://test.mosquitto.org/mqtt using this approach. You will need to create a similar solution yourself. Apache also has websocket modules that would do this, or you could create your own websocket server using e.g. libwebsockets.

Comment: This is now out of date - test.mosquitto.org is listening for websockets on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
t.connect('ws://localhost:1883',100000);
```

?